# could not open [imagetitle].png

Tags: python, pygame

im learning pygame and im getting the error

```
 File "c:/Users/fester/Documents/pythonProjects/2021/penisRacingGame/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    penisimage = pygame.image.load("pythonProjects\2021\penisRacingGame\car.jpg")
pygame.error: Couldn't open pythonProjects1\penisRacingGame\car.jpg
```

the image is in the same directory as the code, theres no reason i would even need to specify the directory in my code, i only did because i used the code

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

to see where its looking, and it said it was looking in pythonProjects, and not penisRacingGame.
But even then it still gives me the error. any help?

code:

```py
import pygame
import os

print(os.getcwd())

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('i will steal your toes, no exeptions')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

penisimage = pygame.image.load("pythonProjects\2021\penisRacingGame\car.jpg")

def penismove(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(penisimage,(x,y))


x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

crashed = False

while not crashed:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    penismove(x,y)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

code after pathing down to .\pythonProjects\ and making the file name a raw string:

```py
import pygame
import os

print(os.getcwd())

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('i will steal your toes, no exeptions')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

penisimage = pygame.image.load(r".\pythonProjects\2021\penisRacingGame\car.jpg")

def penismove(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(penisimage,(x,y))


x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)

crashed = False

while not crashed:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    penismove(x,y)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

`"\202"` is treated as a character with the hexadecimal charcode `\x82` (decimal 130). You should use a raw string: `r"pythonProjects\2021\penisRacingGame\car.jpg"` or escape the backslashes: `"pythonProjects\\2021\\penisRacingGame\\car.jpg"`.

Comment: (To add `\202` is in octal, e.g. base 8)

Comment: thanks for the raw string tip, but it still isnt working, im still getting the same error, i pathed it down to the directory its looking but it still wont load. ill edit my question to include the new code

Comment: Please update the error message, too.

Comment: Since you have a new problem with a new approach to the code, you should ask a new question rather than editing. While you're at it, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and try to cut down the code to the minimum needed to reproduce the problem. You should also make sure you can explain what a current working directory is, and what you think the current working directory is when you run the program, and why.